# How to automatically inject some text to twitter share box?

Tags: html, twitter, twitter-card

I've added meta tags to show summary_large_image box for twitter share. Once the twitter share window pops up, it looks like this: [image]

Once I clicked `Tweet`, the summary_large_image can be displayed correctly with no problem. Here is the meta code:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="patch-package is like a bandage. It saved my life!!!" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://image.mux.com/d4OkE5whZfyg1VJogOTf8AAHcMG00ak24h6JQYWNo/thumbnail.png?width=700&height=400" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@lonelydotdev" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="react-video-recorder works in firefox now!!!" />
```

But what I really want to see in the share window is something like following, where it not only has the url link, but has some text description, as well as via @username in the end:
[image]

How can I automatically inject the description and site owner to the share `textarea`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `react-share` npm package. It has `via`, `related`, `title` such parameters that I can use to inject those text.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share